# HABTM and belongsTo at the same join, cakePhp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many, belongs-to

I have a model Fix with a relationship HABTM Device model. 
Device model has a belongsTo to Device_type model, like this, for only getting the device type name:

```
var $belongsTo = array('Device_type'=>array('fields'=>'name'));
```

So, I need every Fix, its devices and its Device_types. When I make a `Fix->find('all', array('recursive' => 2))`
I expect to get every Device related to Fix (*this works ok*) and ALSO for every device, its Device_type.name (which is not working).
This is what I get instead for every Device in the result (*an empty array*):

```
["Device_type"]=>
    array(0) {
}
```

Besides this, when I make this query for testing: `Fix->Device->find('all')`, it returns the current Device_type.names for every device related to fixes, which means models are related propertly.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice, is your naming conventions should be lower case under_score for your multi-word table names.

And its also apparent your relationships most likely are not set up correctly if you are not getting the data on a recursive 2.

It's kind of hard to make more judgement with your limited code.

Comment: My table names are correctly in lower case, as far as I know this names are related to models and are set as cake expected them to be. Obvioulsy, there could be a problem with my relationships, that is why I am asking for your help and knowledge, since I am new to cakePhp. There is not really much more coding than I mentioned here, anyway I am still asking for someone's help and a valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to CakePHP and MVC, it would be really best to follow the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog) on the CakePHP web site. From that, you will learn the basics of building a CakePHP app and in the end have  working application which you can "play" with and modify to learn how MVC ticks. You can experiment and learn a lot from this : )